# Python Statsmodel Logistic Regression iterate through Parquet file

Tags: python, logistic-regression, parquet, statsmodels, large-data

I am trying to run a logistic regression model on a very large dataset with 2.3 billion observations in Python. I need a standard regression output. Statsmodels with parquet seemed promising:
https://www.statsmodels.org/v0.13.0/large_data.html

```
import pyarrow as pa
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

class DataSet(dict):
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.parquet = pq.ParquetFile(path)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            return self.parquet.read([key]).to_pandas()[key]
        except:
            raise KeyError

LargeData = DataSet('LargeData.parquet')

res = smf.ols('Profit ~ Sugar + Power + Women', data=LargeData).fit()
```

However it says "Additionally, you can add code to this example DataSet object to return only a subset of the rows until you have built a good model. Then, you can refit your final model on more data."

This is what I tried all day and could not get to work. I am not super familiar with Python classes and how to iterate row-group-wise through a parquet.

I am sure it's only few lines of code, could anyone help me out?

P.S.: Ideally, of course I need the combination of the distributed model and the subsetted data. But I would already be happy to get the subsetting to without running out of memory. Thanks!

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may want to check out [dask-ml](https://ml.dask.org/). It offers a similar interface to scikit-learn but leveraging multiple cores for a partitioned dataset.

Comment: See e.g. [`dask_ml.linear_model.LogisticRegression`](https://ml.dask.org/modules/generated/dask_ml.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#dask_ml.linear_model.LogisticRegression)

Comment: Thanks. And in the dask case, would it be possible to fit row groups iteratively to have a full model for large data?

Comment: Dask would handle processing each group for you. You wouldn’t need to do it iteratively.

Comment: Thanks Michael Delgado, I ended up using dask which solved many problems for me.

Comment: Great to hear! This is a key use case for dask_ml so if you posted a simple version of your solution as an answer I'm sure it would be helpful for others!

Answer (score 0):

You can read "subset" of your parquet file by using row groups:

```py
import random
row_group = random.rand_range(self.parquet.num_row_groups) 
return self.parquet.read_row_group(row_group).to_pandas()
```

I'm not sure how exactly you'd do that in your case, maybe by selecting an arbitrary / random set of available row groups.

Comment: Thanks, I got to work iterating through the row groups by now. But I am still struggling with "return only a subset of the rows until you have built a good model. Then, you can refit your final model on more data". So how do I "refit" in statsmodels? By giving start_params from the previous model to the fit method?